# Source term of Poisson's equation in finite-difference modeling

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, poissons-equation

The Poisson's equation:
$$
\nabla^2\phi=I\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r_s})
$$
with the boundary condition $\phi(\infty)=0$,
where $I$ is a constant and $\vec{r_s}$ is the source location,
has the solution:
$$
\phi(\vec{r})=\frac{I}{4\pi|\vec{r}-\vec{r_s}|}
$$
I am trying to solve this equation in 2D by finite-difference method with grid sizes $dx=dy$. At each grid point not contaning the source, we have the equation:
$$
\frac{1}{4}(\phi_{i,j-1}+\phi_{i,j+1}+\phi_{i-1,j}+\phi_{i+1,j})-\phi_{i,j}=0 \tag{*}
$$
At the soure location, the RHS of (*) must include the source term.

**Question:** If the grid sizes are $dx=dy$, what is the value of the RHS of (*) at the source location?